# Not authenticating custom domain using windows authentication in IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I am facing with a sticky problem as such that i have configured a webapplication in IIS 7.0 and able to authenticate it using windows challenge.able to get a box to enter usename and password.after entering the credentials it directs me to home page.
This is possible if i am accessing via URL http://localhost/

Now comes the problem . I need to call the web app not by localhost but by a custom domain name say http://companyAonline/. I do an Edit binding and put the hostname. I also put an entry in the hosts file under windows. But when I am trying to access the site i get the same windows authentication box. But I am not able to authenticate using the same credentials since the URL has changed.

I have tried numerous ways till date. Setting impersonate =true, Setting the provider for the application pool as NTLM...etc...but no hopes.

Comment: I was having the same issue and found that this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/13017510/3652015 (specifically this link in that post https://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308) helped me resolve the issue.