# How LogonUserIdentity information is passed from browser to server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, authentication, httpcontext

I'm accessing Windows authentication information in my ASP.NET MVC application using the following code.

```
WindowsIdentity identity = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity;
```

Value of **identity.Name** is correctly the Windows login name.

When I inspect the http request that is send from browser to the server I see the following.

```
GET http://localhost:12010/administration HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Negotiate YIIJqgYGKwYBBQUCoIIJnjCCCZqgMDAuBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCqKCCWQEgglgYIIJXAYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBugglLMIIJR6ADAgEFoQMCAQ6iBwMFACAAAACjggfcYYIH2DCCB9SgAwIBBaEKGwhJVC5MT0NBTKIoMCagAwIBAqEfMB0bBEhUVFAbFWl0LWRsMzgyLWhraS5JVC5MT0NBTKOCB5UwggeRoAMCARKhAwIBIaKCB4MEggd
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-EN
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: localhost:12010
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pr0qmeomsr1rlb1ehp2sffd3
```

There is no Windows authentication information in the http request, but I can access it in my code.

How are the values of LogonUserIdentity properties passed from browser to server?

Comment: Can you also give me screenshot for cookie in header value?

Comment: I updated the question. Header has now Cookie and Authorization fields.

Comment: `There is no Windows authentication information in the http request` <- what about in the Authorization field?

Comment: Here are the full explanations of how it works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx

Comment: I updated my answer again for more clarification. may contain your right answer. get ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your WindowsAuthenticationMode, the browser may or may not authenticate with IIS. For example, if you allow Anonymous Authentication, then IUSR_MACHINENAME user will be used to authenticate the user. If Basic is specified, then the browser will authenticate with IIS (you will need to provide user/password) and then you will see in the requests the authentication information. Then there is NTLM authentication. [More information here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647076.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

**Note that** these type of authentication is designed to employ in *intranet applications*.

As you can see, the `Request` parameters for my own test is:

```
Params: {ALL_HTTP=HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL%3amax-age%3d0%0d%0aHTTP_CONNECTION%3akeep-alive%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT%3atext%2fhtml%2capplication%2fxhtml%2bxml%2capplication%2fxml%3bq%3d0.9%2cimage%2fwebp%2c*%2f*%3bq%3d0.8%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING%3agzip%2c+deflate%2c+sdch%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE%3aen-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6%0d%0aHTTP_HOST%3alocalhost%3a54035%0d%0aHTTP_USER_AGENT%3aMozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f40.0.2214.94+Safari%2f537.36%0d%0a&ALL_RAW=Cache-Control%3a+max-age%3d0%0d%0aConnection%3a+keep-alive%0d%0aAccept%3a+text%2fhtml%2capplication%2fxhtml%2bxml%2capplication%2fxml%3bq%3d0.9%2cimage%2fwebp%2c*%2f*%3bq%3d0.8%0d%0aAccept-Encoding%3a+gzip%2c+deflate%2c+sdch%0d%0aAccept-Language%3a+en-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6%0d%0aHost%3a+localhost%3a54035%0d%0aUser-Agent%3a+Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f40.0.2214.94+Safari%2f537.36%0d%0a&APPL_MD_PATH=%2fLM%2fW3SVC%2f7%2fROOT&APPL_
PHYSICAL_PATH=c%3a%5cusers%5camirmehr%5cdocuments%5cvisual+studio+2013%5cProjects%5cWindows+Auth%5cWindows+Auth%5c&AUTH_TYPE=Negotiate&AUTH_USER=Amir%5camirmehr&AUTH_PASSWORD=&LOGON_USER=Amir%5camirmehr&REMOTE_USER=Amir%5camirmehr&CERT_COOKIE=&CERT_FLAGS=&CERT_ISSUER=&CERT_KEYSIZE=&CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE=&CERT_SERIALNUMBER=&CERT_SERVER_ISSUER=&CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT=&CERT_SUBJECT=&CONTENT_LENGTH=0&CONTENT_TYPE=&GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI%2f1.1&HTTPS=off&HTTPS_KEYSIZE=&HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE=&HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER=&HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT=&INSTANCE_ID=7&INSTANCE_META_PATH=%2fLM%2fW3SVC%2f7&LOCAL_ADDR=%3a%3a1&PATH_INFO=%2f&PATH_TRANSLATED=c%3a%5cusers%5camirmehr%5cdocuments%5cvisual+studio+2013%5cProjects%5cWindows+Auth%5cWindows+Auth&QUERY_STRING=&REMOTE_ADDR=%3a%3a1&REMOTE_HOST=%3a%3a1&REMOTE_PORT=54427&REQUEST_METHOD=GET&SCRIPT_NAME=%2f&SERVER_NAME=localhost&SERVER_PORT=54035&SERVER_PORT_SECURE=0&SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP%2f1.1&SERVER_SOFTWARE=Microsoft-IIS%2f8.0&URL=%2f&HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age%3d0&HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive&HTTP_
ACCEPT=text%2fhtml%2capplication%2fxhtml%2bxml%2capplication%2fxml%3bq%3d0.9%2cimage%2fwebp%2c*%2f*%3bq%3d0.8&HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip%2c+deflate%2c+sdch&HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6&HTTP_HOST=localhost%3a54035&HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f40.0.2214.94+Safari%2f537.36}
```

And Server variables :

```
ServerVariables: {ALL_HTTP=HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL%3amax-age%3d0%0d%0aHTTP_CONNECTION%3akeep-alive%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT%3atext%2fhtml%2capplication%2fxhtml%2bxml%2capplication%2fxml%3bq%3d0.9%2cimage%2fwebp%2c*%2f*%3bq%3d0.8%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING%3agzip%2c+deflate%2c+sdch%0d%0aHTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE%3aen-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6%0d%0aHTTP_HOST%3alocalhost%3a54035%0d%0aHTTP_USER_AGENT%3aMozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f40.0.2214.94+Safari%2f537.36%0d%0a&ALL_RAW=Cache-Control%3a+max-age%3d0%0d%0aConnection%3a+keep-alive%0d%0aAccept%3a+text%2fhtml%2capplication%2fxhtml%2bxml%2capplication%2fxml%3bq%3d0.9%2cimage%2fwebp%2c*%2f*%3bq%3d0.8%0d%0aAccept-Encoding%3a+gzip%2c+deflate%2c+sdch%0d%0aAccept-Language%3a+en-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6%0d%0aHost%3a+localhost%3a54035%0d%0aUser-Agent%3a+Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f40.0.2214.94+Safari%2f537.36%0d%0a&APPL_MD_PATH=%2fLM%2fW3SVC%2f7%2fR
OOT&APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH=c%3a%5cusers%5camirmehr%5cdocuments%5cvisual+studio+2013%5cProjects%5cWindows+Auth%5cWindows+Auth%5c&AUTH_TYPE=Negotiate&AUTH_USER=Amir%5camirmehr&AUTH_PASSWORD=&LOGON_USER=Amir%5camirmehr&REMOTE_USER=Amir%5camirmehr&CERT_COOKIE=&CERT_FLAGS=&CERT_ISSUER=&CERT_KEYSIZE=&CERT_SECRETKEYSIZE=&CERT_SERIALNUMBER=&CERT_SERVER_ISSUER=&CERT_SERVER_SUBJECT=&CERT_SUBJECT=&CONTENT_LENGTH=0&CONTENT_TYPE=&GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI%2f1.1&HTTPS=off&HTTPS_KEYSIZE=&HTTPS_SECRETKEYSIZE=&HTTPS_SERVER_ISSUER=&HTTPS_SERVER_SUBJECT=&INSTANCE_ID=7&INSTANCE_META_PATH=%2fLM%2fW3SVC%2f7&LOCAL_ADDR=%3a%3a1&PATH_INFO=%2f&PATH_TRANSLATED=c%3a%5cusers%5camirmehr%5cdocuments%5cvisual+studio+2013%5cProjects%5cWindows+Auth%5cWindows+Auth&QUERY_STRING=&REMOTE_ADDR=%3a%3a1&REMOTE_HOST=%3a%3a1&REMOTE_PORT=54427&REQUEST_METHOD=GET&SCRIPT_NAME=%2f&SERVER_NAME=localhost&SERVER_PORT=54035&SERVER_PORT_SECURE=0&SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP%2f1.1&SERVER_SOFTWARE=Microsoft-IIS%2f8.0&URL=%2f&HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age%3d0&HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-al
ive&HTTP_ACCEPT=text%2fhtml%2capplication%2fxhtml%2bxml%2capplication%2fxml%3bq%3d0.9%2cimage%2fwebp%2c*%2f*%3bq%3d0.8&HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip%2c+deflate%2c+sdch&HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US%2cen%3bq%3d0.8%2cfa%3bq%3d0.6&HTTP_HOST=localhost%3a54035&HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla%2f5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3%3b+WOW64)+AppleWebKit%2f537.36+(KHTML%2c+like+Gecko)+Chrome%2f40.0.2214.94+Safari%2f537.36}
```

which contains my `username` equal to *amirmehr*. But in browser request we don't see any user information which says the IIS is reading user data from OS since I'm running my project locally :). Here is browser request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:54035/
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer:http://localhost:54035/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.94 Safari/537.36
```

After some research, I found out the question depends on test environment (besides configuration).

- *For Local case*, take a look at [Unable to get windows authentication to work through local IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387156/unable-to-get-windows-authentication-to-work-through-local-iis)
- And to understand how it works, check the [Windows Authentication for
  .net MVC 4 - how it works, how to test it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224174/windows-authentication-for-net-mvc-4-how-it-works-how-to-test-it). Both have useful
  things.

Also we have configuration considerations mentioned below:

- [Configuration(*Microsoft Link*)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942043/)
- [Configuring Windows Authentication in MVC4 with IIS Express](http://www.itorian.com/2013/05/windows-authentication-in-mvc4-with-iis.html).

For customization check [ASP.NET MVC 4 Forms Authentication Customized](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/601687/ASP-NET-MVC-Forms-Authentication-Customized) :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My implementation works also in other environment than in localhost. I think the server receives Authorization field in http request and checks if the value is found from Active Directory. That's my best guess and it's also mentioned in other answer's link.