# Windows authentication failing on server side webapi call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, windows-authentication, iis-8

I have got an MVC 5 web application hosted on IIS8 which is secured with Windows Authentication. The application has an WebApi2 controller which I am calling server side from itself via an MVC controller, however I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized when making the call (POST verb).

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, dto).Result;
```

Things I have tried with no success:

- Setting the application pool user identity to a custom account
- Enabling ASP.NET impersonation with account credentials
- Editing the registry to whitelist the domain (as per this solution [Unable to get windows authentication to work through local IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387156/unable-to-get-windows-authentication-to-work-through-local-iis))

Wondering if anyone else has any suggestions/seen this issue before?

Comment: How are you making the call? If you're using http to invoke another controller method, you need to send the authorization headers.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I am using to call the api endpoint

Comment: Okay, yes, that's an HTTP call.  The ASP.Net security context does not translate over HTTP, so you need to add the appropriate authorization headers.

Comment: Ah ok thanks Amy. I will look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me when instantiating my HttpClient.

```
            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
            };
            var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
```