# Windows Authentication not working on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I've exhausted every bit of me to get Windows Authentication to work on the server and I cannot find any help on the internet. Windows authentication is working on my local PC, below is what I've done so far, kindly assist me understand if there's something I am missing or did wrong?

1. Windows Server 2012 R2 (v6.2) with IIS (v8.5.9600)
2. Here's how my web.config looks like:

   `<system.web>
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
       <authentication mode="Windows"/>
       <authorization>
           <deny users="?"/>
       </authorization>
   </system.web>`
3. And here's the authentication section in IIS:

[image]

4. I've added the website as a Trusted Site (also as a Local Intranet) in Internet Explorer and that didn't help:

[image]

5. Many threads (including [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13017510/2811530)) advised I add 2 entries to the registry to:

   - Set the DisableStrictNameChecking registry entry to 1
   - and add my website url in: BackConnectionHostNames

I've done so as per below and still no luck, I've even gone as far as performing the above steps on both the server and my local PC as well:

[image]
[image]

6. And I've mirrored everything else on there as is on my local PC. The server was restarted after doing the above 2 steps. The website is configured to use pass-through authentication in IIS and works fine on my local PC:

[image]

Is there something I am missing or not doing right? I've carried this problem into my New Year and I am so tired of it. Please anyone help me or point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Read IIS log files to learn the substatus code first.

Comment: @LexLi, I can't make sense of it apart from the 401 error that's also displayed in the browser. Do you see something?

`2020-01-09 12:41:26 W3SVC37 MTB-WEB-002 1**.**.***.159 GET / - 80 - **.**.**.113 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+Zoom+3.6.0) __RequestVerificationToken=ecHDMBxt1hvZBCbpxj4J1AUOIwv_FkoJmhQGqNRoEvBCgBbXwPmL6nVdCcID5v5XDkhQe4rlNCB6c5-OJD8nqXbJ_E01;+ASP.NET_SessionId=oemkf4f21x1ws2yjjvws5tiv - www.*****-stage.co.za 401 1 3221225581 1509 1410 62`

Comment: @LexLi the stars above is to just hide the IP address and domain name

Comment: Sounds like you do hit 401.1, which your domain administrators have the knowledge to troubleshoot. If you do want to work on that yourself, at least Windows security event log should get you started on those logon failures.