# Domain user can't be logged in after binding host name IIS

Tags: iis-10

My web site is perfectly working on 8081 port in localhost, In order to provide host name I had to set IIS bindings,
Bindings are set correctly. Additionally I set the host name in host file as well. When I browse website via hostname I am getting below error

"Error Message - HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized"
Please note that I am using IIS 10

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing You'd better use FRT to take a deeper look. It is not likely to be from IIS (as that usually should be 401.1 or 401.3)

Comment: It is recommended that you enable detailed errors in IIS and provide detailed error messages. By the way, does your project work fine in local development environment?

Comment: yes , it is working fine in local development environment , Once i deployed it works in IIS via localhost as well

Comment: Could you provide detailed error message or screenshot of detailed error page? Please pay attention to hiding private information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by following this reference: [Getting windows authentication to work through local IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387156/unable-to-get-windows-authentication-to-work-through-local-iis)

Comment: Hi, I'm glad your problem is solved. There are many responses in the link you provided, could you share the specific solution? You can re-edit your answer to make it more detailed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, even though a link can lead to an awnser it isn't an awnser. Please awnser or give some type of short overview about the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to whitelist a domain specified in the hosts file in order for windows authentication to work. Try these steps:

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`
3. Right-click `Parameters`, click New, and then click `DWORD (32-bit) Value`.
4. Type `DisableStrictNameChecking` and press `ENTER`.
5. Double-click the `DisableStrictNameChecking` registry value and type `1` in the Value data box, click `OK`
6. In Registry Editor, locate and then click the following registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0`
7. Right-click `MSV1_0`, point to `New`, and then click `Multi-String Value`.
8. Type `BackConnectionHostNames`, and then press `ENTER`.
9. Right-click `BackConnectionHostNames`, and then click `Modify`.
10. In the Value data box, type the host name or the host names for the
    sites that are on the local computer, and then click `OK`.
11. Quit Registry Editor, and then restart the IISAdmin service.